# How to import java source code into the project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, import, openpdf

I'm new to Java and got very confused when I encountered a library thats not in .jar form. I want to use openPDF so I downloaded the source code here(https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/releases/tag/1.2.17). Note that I can't use maven since my work computer is not connected to the internet.

I am using IntelliJ and tried to add the .zip file as library by right clicking the project and adding it as a library, just like how I did it with another .jar file. So far got no errors.

However when I try to import in my code following this example(https://netjs.blogspot.com/2018/10/how-to-create-pdf-in-java-using-openpdf.html) it cannot find "com.lowagie".

Comment: Not sure if intellij has built-in logic to look into .zip files for sources. But do give it a try by unzipping it first, and then trying to add the extracted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow and to java!

Try to avoid linking in actual java source files, this will make it harder for you to kepp track of what is your code, and what is someone else's code, especially if you import a lot of projects like that.

If you can't access the internet I suggest downloading a pre-build jar made for that project.

You can manually download this particular jar file from maven central repository, which happens to have this project available.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.librepdf/openpdf/1.2.17

Comment: Yes, I see the irony in suggesting to download something as a solution to not being connected but that's what happened with the zip file too.